# How to create a service that never stops running even if the app is closed by the user (e.g. instagram, whatsapp, facebook)?

Tags: android, service, android-service, mqtt

I'm building an app that uses MQTT protocol to receive a message if a button connected to ESP8266 is pressed (like an alarm system). I'm showing a Toast to indicate that the app received the message from the MQTT Broker that the button was pressed and it works fine so far, even if the app is minimized.

If I close the app (pressing home and removing it from the task manager) it (obviously) stops getting the messages from the MQTT Broker. But I need it to keep receiving the messages and showing the toast. Then I've used a Service to perform that, but the service is stopped when the app is closed. Also tried to use the approach with the BroadcastReceiver:

1. Create MyService class extending Service
2. Create MyBroadcastReceiver enxtending BroadcastReceiver
3. Adding < service > and < receiver > tags to the Android Manifest with the < intent-filter >

For some reason it doesn't work. The broadcast function onReceive() is never called.

My app should work like any social network app (whatsapp, instagram, etc) where a background service keeps running all the time and shows a notification (in this case a Toast) if a new message arrives. So guys, do y'all have any ideas how should I perform that?

Comment: what devices are you testing this on? What version of Android is running on those devices?

Comment: Also, add the code from your `Service.onStartCommand()` to your question

Answer (score 0):

Can you sharing your services class?, if you already have a services running, should be enough using:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    // your code here ....

    return START_STICKY;
}
```

return START_STICKY -> [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service)

Comment: I'm using return START_STICKY but it doesn't seem to work. Once I swipe out the app from the recent tasks the service stops, gets created again, an then destroyed again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use push notifications: FCM for Android and APNs for iOS. And you need a server-side gateway between MQTT and push notifications.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Makes sense, but I still got the issue: How can I make MQTT connection service run all the time? I mean, even If the user closes the app (swipes out from the recent tasks) It should be able to restart the service. How can I acomplish that?